# Using Euclid Algorithm to find GCF(GCD)

Tags: c++, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to write a function to find the gcd of 2 numbers, using Euclid's Algorithm which I found [here](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/gcf.php).

> From the larger number, subtract the smaller number as many times as you can until you have a number that is smaller than the small number. (or without getting a negative answer) Now, using the original small number and the result, a smaller number, repeat the process. Repeat this until the last result is zero, and the GCF is the next-to-last small number result. Also see our Euclid's Algorithm Calculator.
>   **Example: Find the GCF (18, 27)**
>   27 - 18 = 9
>   18 - 9 = 9
>   9 - 9 = 0
>   So, the greatest common factor of 18 and 27 is 9, the smallest result we had before we reached 0.

Following these instructions I wrote a function:

```
int hcf(int a, int b)
{
    int small = (a < b)? a : b;
    int big = (a > b)? a : b;
    int res;
    int gcf;

    cout << "small = " << small << "\n";
    cout << "big = " << big << "\n";

    while ((res = big - small) > small && res > 0) {
            cout << "res = " << res << "\n"; 
    }
    while ((gcf = small - res) > 0) {
        cout << "gcf = " << gcf << "\n";
    }


    return gcf;
}
```

However, the second loop seems to be infinite. Can anyone explain why?

I know the website actually shows the code(PHP), but I'm trying to write this code using only the instructions they give.

Comment: This code is *way* too smart. Keep it simple!

Comment: @BaummitAugen what do you mean by "smart"?

Comment: I mean stuff like `while ((res = big - small) > small && res > 0)`. If you just look at this, it is not trivial to tell what the value of all your variables will be after the loop is done. That is a *very*  bad thing!

Comment: I'd suggest `int gcd(int a, int b) { return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a; }` instead.  Using subtraction just isn't a great idea.

Comment: What you try to implement is not Euclid's algorithm, it's actually way more inefficient, O(n) instead of O(log n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course this loop is infinite:

```
while ((gcf = small - res) > 0) {
    cout << "gcf = " << gcf << "\n";
}
```

`small` and `res` don't change in the loop, so `gcf` doesn't either. That loop is equivalent to:

```
gcf = small - res;
while (gcf > 0) {
    cout << "gcf = " << gcf << "\n";
}
```

which is probably more clear.

I would port that algorithm to code as follows:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            a -= b;
        }
        else {
            b -= a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Although typically `gcd` is implemented using mod, since it's much faster:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```