# How do I convert this code into an array or malloc?

Tags: c, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial(int n) {
    int f;

    for(f = 1; n > 0; n--)
        f *= n;
    return f;
} 

int ncr(int n,int r) {
    return factorial(n) / ( factorial(n-r) * factorial(r) );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int n, i, j;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

        printf("1");

        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            if(i == j && j > 0) printf(" 1");
            else printf(" %d", ncr(i, j));

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I test it with the argument of a number that is above 12, I get strange numbers from row 12(?).. Why is this happening? should I use malloc or array? Can someone please change this codes into an array or malloc? Thanks.

Comment: Factorials get huge pretty quickly, and the integer type is very soon incapable of representing such big numbers...

Comment: If you really need to work with such large numbers, consider something like the [GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: If you're trying to work out probabilities you should consider using `double`. You will lose precision but if you multiply as you go along you should be OK. Remember that n!/m! means you can avoid doing the multiplications on the top or bottom for min(m,n) That is 12!/10! is obviously 12*11 = 132 because 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10 cancelled.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43348387/2410359) can help handle very wide integer multiplication/division.

Comment: used long long and am now able to handle with the argument upto 20, however I still get cracked number when the argument is 66...

Comment: 66! is a very huge number, 70! is close to a Googol. You really should not be trying to compute such huge numbers, even with MPI libraries. Try to change the logic so such huge numbers don't come up.

Answer (score 1):

Why strange? Factorial 13 is 6227020800, which exceeds INTMAX so you wrap into negative land.  "long long" would likely work.  Get to know the MAX and MIN values in  for size limits.

Always be sure of your ranges before you start designing a program.

Comment: I used long long and am now able to handle with the argument upto 20, however I still get cracked number when the argument is 66...

Comment: Factors grow hugely quickly. Look at https://gmplib.org/. Try rolling your own for a 60-digit power of two program in an unsigned char array, one digit in each char... unsigned char digits[60].